# Gatsby - Build console warning: MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I am Building a gatsby website and everything works fine but I keep getting this error in the console:

```
   ⠁ (node:32096) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. U
se emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I understand what it is, and I understand this is just a warning, but I would like to fix it. I google anywhere and asked also in the Gatsby chat, but no one has been able to help me.

It it happens only when I run

```
yarn start
```

which basically is

```
npm run clean && gatsby develop
```

It happens right after the queries are extracted:

```
success extract queries from components — 0.222 s
```

And before they run

```
success run graphql queries — 4.371 s — 280/280 64.09 queries/second
```

This is driving me crazy and I cannot find a solution, the console does not give me any --trace so I have no idea where this is coming from.

I looked anywhere in github, chats and google but there is no way to find a fix for this. At least I would be able to debug it, but I have no idea how to print the stack trace in the console.

After running

```
gatsby clean
```

Now is not a warning anymore, is an error ...

```
error (node:32210) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using both yarn and node?

Comment: Actually this was the confusion. I run a npm ci and removed the node folder and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks might be in the internal code or within `node_modules/`.

To inspect where the warning/error was created, run the start script with `--trace-warnings` node option:

```
node --trace-warnings node_modules/.bin/gatsby develop
```

The output will change from:

```
(node:30590) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [PassThrough]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

To a more verbose:

```
(node:31861) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [PassThrough]. Use
emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (node:events:587:17)
    at PassThrough.addListener (node:events:605:10)
    at PassThrough.Readable.on (node:internal/streams/readable:887:35)
    at eos (node:internal/streams/end-of-stream:177:10)
    at pipe (node:internal/streams/pipeline:392:10)
    at pipelineImpl (node:internal/streams/pipeline:323:25)
    at pipeline (node:internal/streams/pipeline:151:10)
    at probeStream (/node_modules/probe-image-size/stream.js:63:8)
    at get_image_size (/node_modules/probe-image-size/index.js:13:12)
    at getImageSizeAsync (/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp/index.js:63:28)
    at getImageMetadata (/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp/image-data.js:33:39)
    at generateImageData (/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp/image-data.js:123:26)
    at /node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/dist/node-apis/image-processing.js:255:42
    at step (/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/dist/node-apis/image-processing.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/dist/node-apis/image-processing.js:14:53)
```

Hopefully, the verbose output is going to give a clue where's the root cause of the problem.